# C# Bitwise operations Generic class

Tags: c#, .net, math, bitwise-operators

I am writing a c# bitwise operations class.

I have the following enum

```
public enum Fruits
{
  Apple = 1,
  Orange= 2,
  Mango = 3,
  Grapes = 4,
  Pineapple = 5
}
```

I need to store one or more flags for example 1,3,4,5 in a bit, that is a value stored can be 1 or more.

Is there a generic c# class that can do this for me? When I read data I should be able to read them as integers corresponding enum flag.

Comment: Are you looking for [`FlagsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-7.0)? See the examples in the documentation for more details.

Comment: Just keep in mind in such case better to go with powers of 2, instead of 1,2,3,4,5 as your current values might be problematic to distinct: is 5 a Pineapple value or Orange+Mango?

Comment: Note that the [Flags] attribute does *very little* and in particular leaves choosing suitable values (powers of two) entirely up to you.

Comment: Can you describe what operations you need? Several generic classes already exist, e.g. BitVector or HashSet

Comment: @PMF, I need conversion of int value to bits and back, bits to int.

Comment: Have you tried `System.Collections.BitArray`?

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago, long before `IBinaryInteger<TSelf>` was added - my solution used `where TEnum : struct, Enum` and used runtime reflection to generate raw IL for bitwise operations over every `TEnum` (regardless of `TEnum`'s backing-type: `int`, `long`, etc). It was a lot of code - so just warning you, it might just be easier to write methods for each `enum` type you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below can help you:

```
using System;
namespace NsEnumFruits {
    class EnumFruits {
        [Flags]
        public enum Fruits {
          Apple = 1,
          Orange = 2,
          Mango = 4,
          Grapes = 8,
          Pineapple = 16
        }       
        [Flags]
        public enum Hybrids {
          EmptyOrDonutHole = 0,
          Apple = 1,
          Pine = 2,
          Pineapple = 3
        }       
        static void Main() {
            var ef = new Fruits(); ef = Fruits.Orange;
            Console.WriteLine("ef is {0}, ef as integer is {1}", ef, (int)ef);
            ef = Fruits.Apple;
            Console.WriteLine("Now ef is {0}, ef as integer is {1}", ef, (int)ef);
            ef = (Fruits)4;
            Console.WriteLine("Now ef is {0}, ef as integer is {1}", ef, (int)ef);
            var efv = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits));
            foreach (int i in efv) Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", (Fruits)i, Math.Log(i, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(new Hybrids());
            var ema = Hybrids.Apple; var emp = Hybrids.Pine;
            Console.WriteLine("You can cross the plants (e. g. {1} and {2}) to get a hybrid {0}", ema | emp, ema, emp);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

ef is Orange, ef as integer is 2

Now ef is Apple, ef as integer is 1

Now ef is Mango, ef as integer is 4

Apple, 0

Orange, 1

Mango, 2

Grapes, 3

Pineapple, 4

EmptyOrDonutHole

You can cross the plants (e. g. Apple and Pine) to get a hybrid Pineapple

Comment: @harold it depends. Modified.

Comment: Thanks for the example @rotaboe, however, I cannot declare hybrid. I need to get the bitwise shift value of selected enum items.

Comment: You need to convert an enum to the int as sampled above then shift it anywhere :-)